# Editing a text file to make the url's show correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "/xxxx/xxxxxxxx-" in a['href']:
        x = ("https://www.unkown.com" + a['href'])
        # print(x)
        f.write(x)
    else:
        pass
```

when I do f.write(x) all that is getting saved is :
[Click to view the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gti5z.png)
how do I separate all the https://www.unkown.com/xxxx/xxxxxx-6xxxxx from each other

Tried putting them in a array and then printing them out but that didn't work because array x[0] is all the url's

Comment: instead do `x = ("https://www.unkown.com" + a['href'] + '\n')` to add a new line character to separate each link

Comment: Change *f.write(x)* to *print(x, file=f)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to `x = ("https://www.unkown.com" + a['href'] + '\n')` so each link can be separated.

Comment: the issue was there was no \n the end :) thanks aditpatel for the help